# Can't set 64 bit target for Setup Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2017

I'm going round in circles trying to build an MSI installer for 64 bit output.  I'm using visual studio 2017 with the [Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) add-on from the store.

I just cant find a way to set the target to 64 bit.

I'm getting the error:

```
Building file 'C:\Users\philip\git\foo\Installer\Debug\Installer.msi'...
Building file 'C:\Users\philip\git\foo\Installer\Debug\Installer.msi'...
ERROR: File 'foo.Core.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'foo.Core.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'foo.Core.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'foo.Core.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
```

When I try to change the target, I'm not given any options.

[image]
[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The architecture is specified in the setup project's properties window which, confusingly enough, is not the same as the property pages, which is what you are showing there.

If you select the setup project in solution explorer and click F4 you sould see the properties window with AddRemoveProgramsIcon, Manufacturer and so on. Down that list is TargetPlatform where you specify x86 or x64.

Comment: Having read 8 different tutorials. None of them mentioned the difference between property pages and properties window.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, like the OP, went through all properties page I could find, they had this one squirreled away well!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I would take me a while to find this.
It is on View -> Other Windows -> Properties Window

Comment: Thank you sir, this was super helpful, I wonder why is the option hidden like this.

Comment: My god I was stuck on this for like an hour! If I could upvote twice I would :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times, and f4 as decribed above didnt work for me.   There are 2 ways to open the Properties.    a)  inside the solution explorer select the second item (not the thing that starts with ´solution ...´ . The second item will have an icon with a cd in the lower left corner). It is really necessary to select this first. If you do select anything else the "real" properties entry will never show.  b)  Then go to the top menu "View" and go down to the second last entry , this is named "Properties Window". Do not use the last entry (which is named "Property Pages").

The second way to do this is going to the "quick launch"
text entry, which is by default on the top line, it has a search icon.  Type in "properties".  This will show all kind of property related items. You need to select the "View -> Properties Window" item.

I also think that there could be a bug in the UI, so the first time you try to reach it via "solution explorer" the menu entry is not yet available. In this case the path via "quick launch" is better.