# Unable to specify project of solution for MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

I have the following solution:

```
MySolution\
   MySolution.sln
   MyCSProject\
      MyCSProject.csproj
   MyCPPProject\
      VC11\
         projfile.vcxproj
      VC8
         projfile.vcproj
   MyInstallationProject
      MyInstallationPackage.vdproj
```

In Visual Studio I have `MyCSProject` set as main project. But for automated build I need to build `MyInstallationProject` with dependencies. `MyInstallationProject` depends on `MyCSProject` and `MyCSProject` depends on `MyCPPProject`. If I build from Visual Studio, it works.

But for MSBuild I can't compose correct command. Neither of the following worked:

```
"...\MSBuild.exe" MySolution.sln /t:MySolution\MyInstallationProject /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"

"...\MSBuild.exe" MySolution.sln /t:MySolution\MyInstallationProject.vdproj /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"

"...\MSBuild.exe" MySolution.sln /t:MyInstallationProject /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"

"...\MSBuild.exe" MyInstallationProject\MyInstallationProject.vdproj /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"
```

and so on, with various errors, mainly "The target *** does not exist in the project"

How to know correct command and or the name of target, associated with the project?

Comment: `/t:MyInstallationProject` This should work, as long as the name matches the project name listed in the `.sln` file (which may or may not be the same as the `.vdproj` name). Try adding `/verbosity:diag` to the `msbuild` command line, maybe it provides more clues.

Answer (score 1):

**In fact,** one of the third and the fourth msbuild command line should have worked in your side. Also, there is [a document about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019).

The truth is that MSBuild cannot build the `vdproj` file. It is from VS installer project extension and the build tool is a separate tool from the extension rather than in the MSBuild. You can easily open the `vdproj` file and could find that it is not a xml style.

MSBuild can only build the xml sytle proj file.

**To** test it, you could try the same msbuild command line for `MyCSProject` project to get the difference.

So the right way is to use VS IDE build or use [devenv build command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) which means you have to you have VS IDE on your local.

Try the following command line:

**1)** open Developer Command Prompt for VS:

**2)** run:

```
cd xxx\xxx\MySolution
devenv MyInstallationProject\MyInstallationProject.vdproj /build
```

Comment: Hm... I need this to work in `CI` environment of azure pipelines....

Comment: `devenv <solutionfilename> /build` does nothing; `devenv <projectdirectory>\<projectfilenam> /build` does nothing; `devenv <solutionfilename> /build /project <projectdirectory>\<projectfilenam>` displays error window `Missing switch argument. Configuration name required for /build switch.`

Comment: @Dims See also [How to build visual studio installer project (.vdproj) from jenkins to generate .exe and .msi files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781446/how-to-build-visual-studio-installer-project-vdproj-from-jenkins-to-generate) and links therein.

Comment: @Dims, you have to specify the sln full name or vdproj full name, you could use `devenv xxx\MySolution.sln /build` or `devenv xxx\MyInstallationProject.vdproj /build`