# "Incompatible platform error" building MSI

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, .net-4.5

I have a Windows service application and am trying to add an MSI project to the solution. Application uses 64 bit Oracle Data Access DLL and is built as 64 bit app.

I added new "Project Setup" project to the solution and went through the steps. There are two other DLLs in the application project: log4net.dll and System.Net.Http.dll.

Windows Service by itself worked fine. When I try to build the solution, I get `File 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'` error. I checked for this error and every article said to set the taget platform of installer to x64, which makes sense. The only thing is when I open the properties window of installer project, there is no option to select target platform and it is blank.

This is screen shot of "Application Folder" section of installer:

[image]

This is the installer properties:

[image]

This is the Windows service application's properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Procedure***: You need to set the MSI architecture in the setup project's properties window. This is a different property page than the one you show.

1. Left click the **`Visual Studio Installer Project`** inside the **`Visual Studio Solution`**.
2. Press **`F4`** to go to the property page for the project.
3. In the **`TargetPlatform`** select **`x64`**.

[image: Property Pages]

***Tip***: Try googling the exact error message you get when you face issues like these. Here is a previous answer: [Can't set 64 bit target for Setup Project in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143721/cant-set-64-bit-target-for-setup-project-in-visual-studio-2017) (I added a new one to get a screen shot in).

***Heads-Up***: And a heads-up on the use of Visual Studio Installer projects. They have many limitations: [Visual Studio Publish Project Into One Simple Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893).

***MSI Tools***: Here is a [quick overview of other MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). And [here is a detailed overview / review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941).

---

***Links***:

- [Troubleshooting Setup and Deployment Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/kz0ke5xt(v%3Dvs.100))

Comment: Thank you. I will try to be more precise in future searches.

Comment: No worries, it tends to help. Thought I'd mention it. Please do skim the VS Installer project limitations answer?